Calculation of a rendezvous from an elliptical orbit to another
I am familiar with computing rendezvous maneuvers using a Hohmann transfer when the two orbits are circular. However, when both orbits are highly elliptical, the fairly simple calculations with a constant angular velocity result in only an approximation.
I am looking for a method to accurately calculate the rendezvous between two elliptical orbits. Specifically, i am looking for a method to:

Determine the optimal phase angle at which the transferring object should initiate its maneuver (e.g., change its orbit or fire its engines).
Calculate the waiting time until the maneuver should occur for the most efficient rendezvous.

The orbits are described using their Keplerian elements. Are analytical or numerical methods like integration necessary? Additionally, how might this problem be approached programmatically?

This is the subject of Lambert's problem, a subject on which multiple questions have previously been asked. Lambert's problem, and solutions to it, are how, for example, missions to Mars are solved. I'll be marking this as a duplicate.

There are many, many other related questions; I picked one at random. To see more (many more!), use the search tool to search for Lambert's problem, Lambert's algorithm (or just Lambert), pork chop plot, or porkchop plot.

@DavidHammen I looked at your proposed duplicate, "picked at random". I don't see anything there that tells this new user HOW to do it. Shouldn't you have least found a proposed duplicate that is helpful to the OP? That question begins "I'm solving the Lambert's problem, and already have written a program..." and so seems particularly unhelpful/unsuitable as a close target.

@DavidHammen in fact, I feel that "Are analytical or numerical methods like integration necessary? Additionally, how might this problem be approached programmatically?" really deserves a good answer, not a "picked at random" dupe close. I'm pretty sure "numerical" is the answer to the first part, and some clear explanation, or answer that links to a good explanation of the shooting method would be helpful for the second part.
